# Search with item list in android Studio

Tags: android-studio, search, spinner

I am playing around with the Android studio and trying to use Spinner.
I have created string or items list under the Strings.xml with different items:

```
<string-array name="Websites">
<item>Facebook</item>
<item>Google</item>
<item>MySpace</item>
<item>Gmail</item>
<item>xtra</item></string-array>
```

I also have a search button added in the search.xml

```
    <Spinner android: id="+@id/search1"

  android: layout_width = "match_parent"
  android: layout_height = "match_parent"/>

<Button
  android: id="+@id/search"
  android: layout_width = "match_parent"
  android: layout_height = "match_parent"/>
```

---

What am trying to do is select a spinner category, i.e., Google and click on the button called Search, and it should take me to www.google.com

I have also added the code in java script for the button and spinner.

But don't know how to use the if...else... funcitons for this

Such as if spinner item list = Google then Search button on click event is "www.google.com"

I am only a beginner and I am learning this for professional development.

Please could you advise me how can I make that?

---

Comment: Note: I did add <Uses-permissions>in android.manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can set the spinner with onItemSelectedListener, so that you can catch the event when user select item, like:

```
.......
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
.......
```

, then you can declare one string param to save the selected item name, and when you click the "search" button, just check what string you save and see what url you want to go!

I made a sample for this, maybe it can help you...
https://gitlab.com/cofk0922/SpinnerTest

Comment: Thanks for that. Although, I could not go to that link giving me error 404. could you please re-paste that link again? Thanks.

Comment: Forgive me for my mistake which about not opening the permission to public. Please check the url again!

Comment: Hello Sean, I have tried it and it worked perfectly!!! Thank you so so much man you are legend!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!